# Convert list to numpy array without using much RAM

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to convert a list with shape (1200, 140, 150, 130) to a numpy array, but the standard `numpydata = np.array(mylist)` uses to much memory.

Is there any less memory consuming way to do this?

Comment: What do you expect from numpy's **dense** arrays and your *3276000000* elements?

Comment: @sascha I bet there are even bigger arrays out there and I have about 100GB of RAM.

Comment: Your list will very likely already use up way more memory than the array will. Probably better to avoid creating the list in the first place.

Comment: Can you create `np.zeros((1200,140,150,130))`, that is an array of the required size?  That test whether there's memory for your result.  It certainly possible that `np.array` makes some temporary copy(s) of the input, since it has to read the whole thing to figure out shape and eventual dtype (and possibly convert elements to common dtype).  So there's a lot going on in compiled code.  Iterating on the list and assigning individual (140,150,130) arrays to the `zeros` might reduce the memory use.  With large arrays there's often a trade off between iteration and memory management.

Comment: egal, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If there's memory for the final result, but `np.array` internals is using too much memory, you might get around that processing the list in blocks.  For example:

```
In [236]: res = np.zeros((10,3,4),int)                                                         
In [237]: alist = np.random.randint(0,10,(10,3,4)).tolist()                                    
In [238]: for i,row in enumerate(alist): 
     ...:     res[i] = row 
In [240]: np.allclose(res, np.array(alist))                                                    
Out[240]: True
```

For small arrays this iteration will be slower, but with large ones, memory management issues might out weight the iteration costs.